# Testing Django template with ajax GET request - ajax request isn't invoking

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, django-templates

I've faced with some problem during implementing test for template rendering. 
There are two views:

1. General
2. Block with required data

General(1) template displays some data. This template contains ajax GET call for retrieving data from additional view (2). I want to check these data in my template(1) with test.

I use `client.get(url)` for invoking my template (1). But seems that ajax GET request isn't invoking during test and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

The `django.test.Client` is not a browser, it just makes HTTP requests, thus doesn't know anything about ajax/javascript.

One of the following should help you

1. use `django.test.Client` and assert that

   - the template has the ajax call to the correct url, i.e.: assert that the response contains `<script>myAjaxCallTo('/some/url/')</script>`
   - test the ajax endpoint in isolation that it returns to correct response
2. use `selenium` (together with the `django.test.LiveServerTestCase`)

Comment: Thanks. I thought as much that `django.test.Client` doesn't handle ajax/javascript.